# Why my same ".s3cfg" file is not working on different machines

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have server ec2 instance where I got error :

```
$ sh ami-backup.sh 
----------------------------------
   Thu Sep 24 10:37:47 UTC 2015   
----------------------------------
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

Same script worked on my local machine so I coped ".s3cfg" to that server still it gives same error "Unable to locate credentials"

On my local machine :

```
ashish@ashishk:~$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxx |   awk '{ print $8 }' | sort -n   | grep  "i-" 
i-127fb8df
i-1effb6d3
i-29efe0e4
i-29fd04e4
i-d5888618
```

On my server (ec2 instance) with same ".s3cfg" :

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxx |   awk '{ print $8 }' | sort -n   | grep  "i-" > /tmp/instanceid.txt
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

Why my same ".s3cfg" file is not working on different machines ! Please let me know what is wrong  here Or if I copy ".s3cfg" from machine to another machine will it work or i have to run "aws configure" & configure on new machine also ?

Comment: Also 
$ s3cmd  du -H s3://inksedge-xxxxx
38G      s3://inksedge-xxxxx/......This command is working 

$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxx |   awk '{ print $8 }' | sort -n   | grep  "i-" > /tmp/instanceid.txt
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"........ Then why this not running :(

Comment: what are the contents of `ami-backup.sh`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your server, use `aws configure` to set your `AWS Access key ID`, `Secret Key ID` and other things, before you run your command.

Comment: Or better yet, assign appropriate IAM roles to the servers.